# Powershell Corrupt Json format alternative

Tags: json, powershell

I'Have the Following situation.
I Receive a "JSON" message in the following format.

```
    {
    "alert_type": "RATE_BASED",
    "alert_name": "Process Discovery",
    "search_period": "300000",
    "hit_oeprator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "Source_info": "http://loginsight.ch/",
        "url": "https://loginsight.ch/s/k978la",
        "info": "null",
        "time": "2022-10-24 09:07",
        "messagesString":"[{"text":"Details zur Pipelineausführung für die Befehlszeile: Get-Process. \r\n\r\nKontextinformationen: \r\n\tDetailSequence=1\r\n\tDetailTotal=1\r\n\r\n\tSequenceNumber=49\r\n\r\n\tUserId=test\\testuser\r\n\tHostName=ConsoleHost\r\n\tHostVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tHostId=617fb611-ac04-46ec-b26a-ea40588d28b7\r\n\tHostApplication=C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\r\n\tEngineVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tRunspaceId=c64d0bb9-c73d-41e9-b137-6163143876f0\r\n\tPipelineId=22\r\n\tScriptName=\r\n\tCommandLine=Get-Process \r\n\r\nDetails: \r\nCommandInvocation(Get-Process): \"Get-Process\"\r\n","timestamp":1666602432506,"fields":[{"name":"HostApplication","content":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"},{"name":"eventid","content":"800"},{"name":"CommandLinePS","content":"Get-Process"},{"name":"keywords","content":"Klassisch"},{"name":"level","content":"Informationen"},{"name":"channel","content":"Windows PowerShell"},{"name":"__li_agent_id","content":"DA383F42-5A9C-478D-00CC-3212C9AF9173"},{"name":"providername","content":"PowerShell"},{"name":"hostname","content":"Test.test.test.CH"},{"name":"task","content":"Details zur Pipelineausführung"},{"name":"ScriptName","content":""},{"name":"__li_source_path","content":"10.10.10.10"},{"name":"eventrecordid","content":"92389"}]}]"
}
{
    "alert_type": "RATE_BASED",
    "alert_name": "Process Discovery",
    "search_period": "300000",
    "hit_oeprator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "Source_info": "http://loginsight.ch/",
        "url": "https://loginsight.ch/s/k978la",
        "info": "null",
        "time": "2022-10-24 09:07",
        "messagesString":"[{"text":"Details zur Pipelineausführung für die Befehlszeile: Get-Process. \r\n\r\nKontextinformationen: \r\n\tDetailSequence=1\r\n\tDetailTotal=1\r\n\r\n\tSequenceNumber=49\r\n\r\n\tUserId=test\\testuser\r\n\tHostName=ConsoleHost\r\n\tHostVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tHostId=617fb611-ac04-46ec-b26a-ea40588d28b7\r\n\tHostApplication=C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\r\n\tEngineVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tRunspaceId=c64d0bb9-c73d-41e9-b137-6163143876f0\r\n\tPipelineId=22\r\n\tScriptName=\r\n\tCommandLine=Get-Process \r\n\r\nDetails: \r\nCommandInvocation(Get-Process): \"Get-Process\"\r\n","timestamp":1666602432506,"fields":[{"name":"HostApplication","content":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"},{"name":"eventid","content":"800"},{"name":"CommandLinePS","content":"Get-Process"},{"name":"keywords","content":"Klassisch"},{"name":"level","content":"Informationen"},{"name":"channel","content":"Windows PowerShell"},{"name":"__li_agent_id","content":"DA383F42-5A9C-478D-00CC-3212C9AF9173"},{"name":"providername","content":"PowerShell"},{"name":"hostname","content":"Test.test.test.CH"},{"name":"task","content":"Details zur Pipelineausführung"},{"name":"ScriptName","content":""},{"name":"__li_source_path","content":"10.10.10.10"},{"name":"eventrecordid","content":"92389"}]}]"
}
```

As we can see, this is not a valid json format. But I can't change that.
In my case, I have to extract every data in the message and put it into a hash table like
"alert_type": "RATE_BASED"
"alert_name": "Process Discovery"

And the difficult thing is, that in the messageString Field, are subfileds like this, which needs to be added to the hashtable as well

```
"fields":[{"name":"HostApplication","content":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"},{"name":"eventid","content":"800"},{"name":"CommandLinePS","content":"Get-Process"},{"name":"keywords","content":"Klassisch"},{"name":"level","content":"Informationen"},{"name":"channel","content":"Windows PowerShell"},{"name":"__li_agent_id","content":"DA383F42-5A9C-478D-00CC-3212C9AF9173"},{"name":"providername","content":"PowerShell"},{"name":"hostname","content":"Test.Test.test.CH"},{"name":"task","content":"Details zur Pipelineausführung"},{"name":"ScriptName","content":""},{"name":"__li_source_path","content":"10.10.10.10"},{"name":"eventrecordid","content":"92389"}]
```

Now I thought about, using the substring method to extract the data from the Fields section and then use regexex and ConvertFrom-StringData to add the Key=Value pairs to the hashtable.

But that doesn't work as expected.

Has someone an idea how to solve this issue?

Kind regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 JSON objects in one string, and a quotes that are wrongly placed. If this is the JSON I would be getting I would go to something like fixing the formatting with regex and then splitting the object, which can be done in a better way but here is an example that work with your example

```
$jsonRaw=@"
    {
    "alert_type": "RATE_BASED",
    "alert_name": "Process Discovery",
    "search_period": "300000",
    "hit_oeprator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "Source_info": "http://loginsight.ch/",
        "url": "https://loginsight.ch/s/k978la",
        "info": "null",
        "time": "2022-10-24 09:07",
        "messagesString":"[{"text":"Details zur Pipelineausführung für die Befehlszeile: Get-Process. \r\n\r\nKontextinformationen: \r\n\tDetailSequence=1\r\n\tDetailTotal=1\r\n\r\n\tSequenceNumber=49\r\n\r\n\tUserId=test\\testuser\r\n\tHostName=ConsoleHost\r\n\tHostVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tHostId=617fb611-ac04-46ec-b26a-ea40588d28b7\r\n\tHostApplication=C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\r\n\tEngineVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tRunspaceId=c64d0bb9-c73d-41e9-b137-6163143876f0\r\n\tPipelineId=22\r\n\tScriptName=\r\n\tCommandLine=Get-Process \r\n\r\nDetails: \r\nCommandInvocation(Get-Process): \"Get-Process\"\r\n","timestamp":1666602432506,"fields":[{"name":"HostApplication","content":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"},{"name":"eventid","content":"800"},{"name":"CommandLinePS","content":"Get-Process"},{"name":"keywords","content":"Klassisch"},{"name":"level","content":"Informationen"},{"name":"channel","content":"Windows PowerShell"},{"name":"__li_agent_id","content":"DA383F42-5A9C-478D-00CC-3212C9AF9173"},{"name":"providername","content":"PowerShell"},{"name":"hostname","content":"Test.test.test.CH"},{"name":"task","content":"Details zur Pipelineausführung"},{"name":"ScriptName","content":""},{"name":"__li_source_path","content":"10.10.10.10"},{"name":"eventrecordid","content":"92389"}]}]"
}
{
    "alert_type": "RATE_BASED",
    "alert_name": "Process Discovery",
    "search_period": "300000",
    "hit_oeprator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "Source_info": "http://loginsight.ch/",
        "url": "https://loginsight.ch/s/k978la",
        "info": "null",
        "time": "2022-10-24 09:07",
        "messagesString":"[{"text":"Details zur Pipelineausführung für die Befehlszeile: Get-Process. \r\n\r\nKontextinformationen: \r\n\tDetailSequence=1\r\n\tDetailTotal=1\r\n\r\n\tSequenceNumber=49\r\n\r\n\tUserId=test\\testuser\r\n\tHostName=ConsoleHost\r\n\tHostVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tHostId=617fb611-ac04-46ec-b26a-ea40588d28b7\r\n\tHostApplication=C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\r\n\tEngineVersion=5.1.17763.2931\r\n\tRunspaceId=c64d0bb9-c73d-41e9-b137-6163143876f0\r\n\tPipelineId=22\r\n\tScriptName=\r\n\tCommandLine=Get-Process \r\n\r\nDetails: \r\nCommandInvocation(Get-Process): \"Get-Process\"\r\n","timestamp":1666602432506,"fields":[{"name":"HostApplication","content":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"},{"name":"eventid","content":"800"},{"name":"CommandLinePS","content":"Get-Process"},{"name":"keywords","content":"Klassisch"},{"name":"level","content":"Informationen"},{"name":"channel","content":"Windows PowerShell"},{"name":"__li_agent_id","content":"DA383F42-5A9C-478D-00CC-3212C9AF9173"},{"name":"providername","content":"PowerShell"},{"name":"hostname","content":"Test.test.test.CH"},{"name":"task","content":"Details zur Pipelineausführung"},{"name":"ScriptName","content":""},{"name":"__li_source_path","content":"10.10.10.10"},{"name":"eventrecordid","content":"92389"}]}]"
}
"@


#fix the extra quote from the start of the array
$format1 = $jsonRaw -replace '(?:\"\[)' , '['

#fix the extra quote from the end of the array
$format2 = $format1 -replace '(?:\]\")' , ']'

#split the two JSON objects, unless this can be done in a better way
$format3 = $format2 -split '(}\r)'

$obj1 = $format3[0] + '}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj2 = $format3[2] | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now you have `$obj1` and `$obj2` as powershell objects.
The thing I would investigate on is a way to split the two objects in the JSON in a better way.

Otherwise, if that satisfy you then you can go further with the Regex(not ideal but possible), you can start expanding the messageString `$obj1.messagesString.text` , this will produce :

```
Details zur Pipelineausführung für die Befehlszeile: Get-Process. 

Kontextinformationen: 
    DetailSequence=1
    DetailTotal=1

    SequenceNumber=49

    UserId=test\testuser
    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.17763.2931
    HostId=617fb611-ac04-46ec-b26a-ea40588d28b7
    HostApplication=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    EngineVersion=5.1.17763.2931
    RunspaceId=c64d0bb9-c73d-41e9-b137-6163143876f0
    PipelineId=22
    ScriptName=
    CommandLine=Get-Process 

Details: 
CommandInvocation(Get-Process): "Get-Process"
```

And if you want to break that down in to single strings/variables then you can use Regex groups, I made an example for you here https://regex101.com/r/9OMkH8/1
Then in powershell you can do something like

```
$user=($obj1.messagesString.text -split '(?s)(?<=UserId=)(.*?)(?=\n)')[1]
```

which will make `$user` to be the string `test\testuser`

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply and your poc of it.
I've tried it so far, but there is an error, and I don't know really why you convert the third element of format3 to an JsonObject, because this element is the `"alert_name": "Process Discovery", value`
The main problem is then still how to use the Field MessageString and extract the values.
I still belive I have to do it with regex

Comment: I think I understood what you mean, check the update @flaeckli

Comment: @flaeckli, did that answer your question ?

Comment: Many Thanks for your help. the thing, Issue which I found might be a an additional convert problem.
Because in the messagesString exist a field of the type System.Object, which contains subfields (which I need) but when I try to Convert it, the System.Object will not be converted.
 `Details: 
                 CommandInvocation(Get-Process): "Get-Process"
                 ; timestamp=1666602432506; fields=System.Object[]}}`
What is the best approach here to create a solid hash table at the end with every entry of the whole obj1 or obj2, ... ,objectn ?

Comment: @flaeckli , This is because the original object were converted to JSON but the object exceeded the default depth. So when the first conversion happens, if its powershell it needs to go like so `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5` where `-Depth` indicates how far inside the object the conversion should take place and everything beyond that will be markt as `System.Object`

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as the `solution` to your question.